# VS2015 ASP.NET MVC the name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nuget, visual-studio-2015

I was working on an ASP.NET MVC 4 in VS2013 and everything was fine, then I've uninstalled 2013 and installed 2015, I was able to open the project, build it and even run, everything works fine (run/debug). The problem is that all my views are covered in errors:

```
the name 'model\Scripts\Url...' does not exist in the current context
```

In addition, the .Where method of a list in the model shows an error as well as all the @Html helpers. I want to emphasize that the project still works w\o any problems so the issue is UI or package related. I tried to force uninstall\upgrade Microsoft.AspNet.MVC but the package manager console throws an error and rolls back the attempt. I can provide any necessary info if it helps, thank you in advance.

Comment: FYI - off topic, but you don't need to uninstall VS2013 to install VS2015. They will run side by side.

Comment: Most likely it's just another bug in new VS...

Comment: I had to uninstall it to get some free space on my drive, otherwise I would have kept it

Comment: Just a guess: do you have assembly binding redirects in web.config for Razor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The newly released VS2015 IDE seems to no longer support MVC3/MVC4 projects, while it only supports the MVC5:

[Unable to find MVC3 , MVC4, MVC5 projects (or) No information about supported MVC Framework versions](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/1321854/)

If there are strict requirements to convert any existing MVC3/4 solution to MVC5 (for VS 2015), you can proceed with the steps listed in the 
[How to Upgrade an ASP.NET MVC 4 and Web API Project to ASP.NET MVC 5 and Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) guide.

### Update 2016-05-03

It seems that after installing the [VS 2015 SP2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx) update, it behaves much better. If you have a chance, I suggest that you upgrade your IDE and check if the issue goes away.

Comment: While it may work at runtime, it may fail at VS, because of the aforementioned issue. You can try to post a follow-up to that issue regarding this.

Comment: @HardLuck You could host the project in IIS and attach a debugger when you need it.

Comment: If there are strict requirements to convert any existing MVC3/4 solution to MVC5 (for VS 2015), you can proceed with the steps listed in the 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2 guide.

Comment: Had to install VS2013 back and use it as VS2015 is not suited for mvc 4 and lower, thanks.

Comment: I was also experiencing this issue in a MVC4 project at work. A reason for the dropped MVC3/4 support might be the upcoming end of support for the NET 4.0/4.5.x framework in Jan 12, 2016.

MVC4 is the last version that runs on the NET 4.0 platform.

Comment: Is that really the best migration path available? Hand-edit the .csproj file and change GUIDs? Feels so 90's.

Comment: This is what I have found in the docs... I have not seen any tool... Based on my personal experience, it is easier to create a new brand MVC 5 project with a valid configuration and migrate source code files.

Comment: It seems that after installing the VS 2015 SP2 https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx update, it behaves much better. If you have a chance, I suggest that you upgrade your IDE and check if the issue goes away.